# My asp.net site has stopped giving me control not found error

Tags: asp.net

I work in an asp.net website, Earlier if I remove any control from my page and it has references in javascript something like this

```
$('#<%= txtName.ClientID %>') // just an example of use
```

it used to give me the error saying something like "txtName does not exist", showing the exact line where the problem is, which helps me figure out the cause and rectify it easily.

But from last many days it has stopped giving me above type of error but it just shows

```
XML parsing error: no element found
Location: 
Line number 1: ...
```

That's make it hard to find the problem. Any idea why it has stopped this behavior?

**Edit**

Today I just added two Title elements by mistake in <%@ Page directive and it started giving me the XML parsing error, earlier it used to give me error something like "Title cannot be defined multiple times" !!!

Answer (score 0):

IF the control has been removed by javascript client side then $('<%= txtName.ClientID %>') will not return an error, it will just return an empty array.  Also the syntax would be $('#<%= txtName.ClientID %>') for the jQuery.  Look what renders out to the browser in firebug or similar.

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't say the control is removed by javascript I said if I remove any control from my page and it has reference in javascript then I used to get the correct error but not I don't

Comment: I was just guessing, if there is no control called txtName in the page, your page should throw a compilation error when you try to access it.  If it does not throw an error, look at the HTML that is rendered, if your code has some ID in place then it is finding a control with a server side ID txtName.

Comment: Sorry when i say a compilation error i don't mean a build error in visual studio I mean a markup compilation error.  These happen at run time when you first access the page unless you use the aspnet precompiler.

Comment: Got you, thats why I removed my comment :) and Exactly, it used to throw the compilation error when I try to access the page but now it has stopped this behavior. I cannot find anything in the page even using firebug as it does not render anything except the xml parsing error